# Conditional step in pipeline executed only based on output of a previous setp

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

sorry I'm not an expert in Jenkins pipelines but maybe someone can point me in the correct direction

I am trying to do something similar to this posts but I have yet to figure it out.

[Conditional step in a pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708783/conditional-step-in-a-pipeline)

[How to run a conditional step in Jenkins only when a previous step fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966094/how-to-run-a-conditional-step-in-jenkins-only-when-a-previous-step-fails)

https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/

So what I want to achieve is the following.

I have a script that fetches some files and stores them in my project
I want at a second stage run it so that I create a PR if there are some changes in the files that were fetch. The idea is run this pipeline daily/weekly

So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Definitions updated') {
      steps {
        sh "./gradlew updateDefinitions"
        gitStatus = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git status').trim()
        ## how to expose gitStatus to the outside
      }
    }
    stage ('Create PR') {
      when {
        // Only say hello if a "status returned something"
        ## how to use the gitStatus to check against a certain output
        expression { SOMETHING == 'SOMETHING'' }
      }
      steps {
        sh "git add ."
        etc...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some I'm not really sure how can I for example store something out of my sh command into my environment variables so that I could use it later in the condition of the next step.

I also don't know exactly if I understood correctly that this will run in parallel or not, I hope all stages are sequential but I'm not 100% sure.

Is there any example I could figure out something similar to out to store output of a sh into an environment variable?

Thank you for any feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can declare the gitStatus outside the pipeline block as below

```
def gitStatus

pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Definitions updated') {
      steps {
        sh "./gradlew updateDefinitions"
        gitStatus = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git status').trim()
        ## how to expose gitStatus to the outside
      }
    }
    stage ('Create PR') {
      when {
        // Only say hello if a "status returned something"
        ## how to use the gitStatus to check against a certain output
        expression { gitStatus == 'SOMETHING'' }
      }
      steps {
        sh "git add ."
        etc...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks actually I realized I can probably define the value in my environment block, it was giving me an error when I later try to re-assign it. but the most basic question about comparing strings in the expression is driving me crazy "hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: gitStatus for class: WorkflowScript"

Comment: It should work without defining it outside as well. Since variable definitions without the `def` keyword are treated as global variables. In a declarative pipeline it probably must be put inside a script block.